# Dependency problem with Entity API + Rules + Features at deployment

Tags: 7, rules, features, entities

I'm saving rules in a feature. I added a new rule that has as dependency a module that I added to the project's repo. This new module was correctly added to the feature's dependency list in the .info file.

The problem occurred when I tried to deploy the changes to a new server. My usual deployment routine goes like this:

```
drush fr-all -y
drush updb -y
drush cc all
```

The deployment choked on `drush cc all` saying:

> WD php: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'plugin' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {rules_config} (name, status, module) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,         [error]
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array
>   (
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => rules_new_report
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 2
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => checkdesk_core_feature
>   )

I was able to fix this error by enabling the new module *manually* before running `drush cc all`. This is not a good solution as I don't want to change my deployment routine for arbitrary deployments.

I think I traced the problem to Entity API's `hook_flush_caches` being called before Features'. In this function, Entity API ends up reloading the default rules, which fails because the new module which is listed as a dependency of the feature hasn't been enabled yet. It will only be enabled when Features' `hook_flush_caches` runs. I tried to mess with module weights but without success.

Any idea for a robust solution to this?

Comment: What versions of the modules are you using?  Also, why are you posting this here rather than in Entity's issue queue?

Comment: I'm using Entity API 7.x-1.0-rc3, Rules 7.x-2.2, Features 7.x-1.0.

Comment: I've posted here because I'm not even sure whose problem it is.

Comment: Submitted support request against Entity API: http://drupal.org/node/1799666